# Preventing Page Scroll When at the End of Table Scroll

Tags: sapui5

Let's say that I have a Page that has a Table inside of it at the top.

When I am scrolling through the Table, there is no problem. The Table scrolls and the Page does not.

But when I reach the bottom of the Table and I'm in the middle of scrolling, the Page will pick it up and start scrolling.

How can I prevent this from happening?

My intended behavior would be:

If the user is scrolling and reaches the bottom of the Table, the page should not scroll once the Table scroll reaches the bottom if the user still has the mouse over the Table.

If the user mouses outside of the Table and scrolls, the Page start scrolling.

I've been researching this problem, but I can't seem to find the right keywords for google, sap, or stackoverflow.